# Two dua's needed in MP3 format

Tags: sunni, dua

Anyone know where I can get the following dua's from in MP3 format?

---

Dua 1:

Arabic:
اللهم رب الناس، مذهب البأس، اشف أنت الشافي، لا شافي إلا أنت، شفاءً لا يغادر سقماً

Transliteration:
Allahumma Rabban-nasi, mudh-hibal-ba'si, ishfi Antash-Shafi, la shafiya illa Anta, shifa'an la yughadiru saqaman

Translation:
O Allah! the Rubb of mankind! Take away this disease and cure (him or her). You are the Curer. There is no cure except through You. Cure (him or her), a cure that leaves no disease

Source:
http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/7/10

---

Dua 2:

Arabic:
بسم الله أرقيك ، من كل شيء يؤذيك، ومن شر كل نفس أو عين حاسد، الله يشفيك، بسم الله أرقيك

Transliteration:
Bismillahi arqika, min kulli shay'in yu'dhika, min sharri kulli nafsin aw 'ayni hasidi, Allahu yashfika, bismillahi arqika

Translation:
With the Name of Allah. I recite over you (to cleanse you) from all that troubles you, and from every harmful mischief and from the evil of the eyes of an envier. Allah will cure you; and with the Name of Allah, I recite over you

Source:
http://sunnah.com/riyadussaliheen/7/15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found them in YouTube:

Dua 1: https://youtube.com/watch?v=Ypvq9UMlSXI

Dua 2: https://youtube.com/watch?v=k6TZZXeFfX4 (the 1st 13 seconds)

Edit:

You can download them from YouTube using applications or sites as mp3. (e.g.www.youtube-mp3.org or www.vidtomp3.com)